# Iptables - VPN firewall to firewall

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I am new to the Linux world and I would like to ask a question regarding the iptables firewall.
A customer asks me to create a firewall-to-firewall connection to their VPN.
What rules should I set to do this?
I know your public IP and your local network range, do I need more information?
Thanks in advance for your help.
PD

---

It is a site to site vpn in IKEv2 mode

---

I try to write my problem better:

```
 ----------------------             ----------------------
|  LAN-A 10.0.x.x/24   |           |  APP                 |
|  PublicIP 82.70.x.x  |<----------|  LAN-B 192.0.x.x/24  |
|  RDP                 |           |  PublicIP 64.15.x.x  |
 ----------------------             ----------------------
```

I need to configure my LAN-B network to LAN-A through a site to site VPN tunnel in IKEv2 mode.
The IP address is NAT.
I will have to connect via RDP from a PC connected in LAN-B to LAN-A.
I have tried several rules found online but without success.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an IPsec IKEv2 VPN tunnel?

Comment: "_I have tried several rules found online_" so that we don't waste our time - or yours - please show what you've already tried, and explain as best you can why it didn't work